# Best way to configure Gerrit repo server-side hooks

Tags: hook, gerrit

By default Gerrit has it's hooks in $site_path/hooks, which in my case is right in the install folder. However this is per instance. I've done some tests, and it works like a charm.

I've figured I can use the call method to do a check to see from what project the hooks were triggered and then trigger a specific script, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at the [Git::Hooks](http://search.cpan.org/~gnustavo/Git-Hooks-1.12.4/). We use it at our company to perform automated verifications and it's really useful.

You can configure which scripts will be executed using the Git config files. For instance, you can set in $HOME/.gitconfig to make some general checks for all repositories, in $site_path/git/.git/config set other tests only for some group of repositories and, finally, in $site_path/git/.git/config configure verifications only for some specific repositories.

[image: Git::Hooks on Gerrit server]

Comment: Are you sure that this also works for the server side?

Comment: Yes. We have it installed in our Gerrit server and it works pretty well.